# Pandas groupby time and ID and aggregate

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am trying to calculate, what is the sum of payment made 2nd half of year minus the 1st half of the year.

This is how the data may look:

```
   ID   date    payment
    1   1/1/2020    10
    1   1/2/2020    11
    1   1/3/2020    10
    1   1/4/2020    10
    1   1/5/2020    11
    1   1/6/2020    10
    1   1/7/2020    10
    1   1/8/2020    11
    1   1/9/2020    10
    1   1/10/2020   32
    1   1/11/2020   10
    1   1/12/2020   12
    2   1/1/2020    10
    2   1/2/2020    10
    2   1/3/2020    41
    2   1/4/2020    10
    2   1/5/2020    53
    2   1/6/2020    10
    2   1/7/2020    10
    2   1/8/2020    44
    2   1/9/2020    10
    2   1/10/2020   2
    2   1/11/2020   9
    2   1/12/2020   5
```

I convert the df date to a pandas dt

```
df.date = df.date.astype(str).str.slice(0, 10)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(pay.date)

print(df.date.min(),df.date.max()) 
output: 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00
```

Then i create time points and different data frames for 1st and 2nd half of the year

```
observation_date = '2020-12-31'
observation_date = datetime.strptime(observation_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
observation_date = observation_date.date()
observation_date = pd.Timestamp(observation_date)
print(observation_date)         

mo6_ago = observation_date - relativedelta(months=6) 
mo6_ago = pd.Timestamp(mo6_ago)
print(mo6_ago)

mo6_ago_plus1 = observation_date - relativedelta(months=6) + relativedelta(days=1)
mo6_ago_plus1 = pd.Timestamp(mo6_ago_plus1)
print(mo6_ago_plus1)

mo12_ago = observation_date - relativedelta(months=12) + relativedelta(days=1)
mo12_ago = pd.Timestamp(mo12_ago)
print(mo12_ago)

output:
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2020-06-30 00:00:00
2020-07-01 00:00:00
2020-01-01 00:00:00

mask = (df['date'] >= mo12_ago) & (df['date'] <= mo6_ago)
first_half = df.loc[mask]
first_half = first_half[['ID','date','payment']]
print(first_half.date.min(),first_half.date.max())

output: 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-06-01 00:00:00

mask = (df['date'] >= mo6_ago_plus1) & (df['date'] <= observation_date)
sec_half = df.loc[mask]
sec_half = sec_half[['ID','date','payment']]
print(sec_half.date.min(),sec_half.date.max())

output: 2020-07-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00
```

then i group and sum for the 2 half of the year and merge them into one df like that

```
sum_first_half = first_half.groupby(['ID'])['payment'].sum().reset_index()
sum_first_half = sum_first_half.rename(columns = {'payment':'payment_first_half'})

sum_sec_half = sec_half.groupby(['ID'])['payment'].sum().reset_index()
sum_sec_half = sum_sec_half.rename(columns = {'payment':'payment_sec_half'})

df_new = pd.merge(sum_first_half, sum_sec_half, how='outer', on='ID')
```

Finally i take minus the 2 columns this way

```
df_new['sec_minus_first'] = df_new['payment_sec_half'] -df_new['payment_first_half']

ID  payment_first_half  payment_sec_half    sec_minus_first
1         62                    85               23
2        134                    80              -54
```

Is there a faster and more memory efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Convert date column to datetime:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Split on a date of your choice, group by ID, sum each half, then subtract the halves:

```
df.loc[df['date'] >= dt(2020, 7, 1)].groupby("ID").sum() - df.loc[df['date'] < dt(2020, 7, 1)].groupby("ID").sum()
```

Comment: Thank you!!  May i ask that dt(2020, 7, 1) is the slicing point for the first and second half of year so it is saying 2020/7/1?

Comment: Yes, it is creating a datetime date on Year=2020, Month=7, Day=1. See linked docs

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I cant believe the solution was that short.

Comment: I am suppose to click the tick button on this post right? sorry i am very new

Comment: If you find any answer helpful you can upvote it (click the up arrow on the left of the question to make it orange). If it is the answer that best solves your question you should accept it (green checkmark). So far you have accepted the answer. I can't see if you upvoted it or if someone else upvoted it.

Comment: Done! Thank you again!